# Can I use 3/4" or 5/8" heater hose instead of 18 mm?

Tags: motorcycle, coolant, hose

I have a '94 Honda VFR and two of the coolant hoses are 18 mm ID.

18 mm is a very unusual ID, and it would be easier to for me to go to the auto parts store and get a size they have in stock, which is 3/4" or 5/8".

Is it at all possible to successfully replace the hoses with a readily available ID?

Comment: If you can get the hose on there, yes. Too small can be stretched over or too large (a little bit) can be pinched with a good hose clamp. If it fits, it ships. I don't know what the difference between 18mm and a 3/4" or 5/8" would be ... I think a 3/4" should be pretty close (just checked, it's a shade large at +.041"). You should be able to take that up with a hose clamp ... use some grease on it (inside) to help it seal.

Comment: That's an answer @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, but I'm not sure the math is right. 3/4" in mm is 19mm.

Comment: 3/4" = 19.05mm (exactly) so in practice it is identical to 19mm. Or equivalently 19mm = 0.748." But 18mm = 0.709 which is significantly smaller than 3/4."

Comment: 39 thousands of an inch is significant? Not when it comes to rubber hoses.

Comment: @GdD - A 3/4" is .750". 18mm equates to ~.709". That's only a difference of .041", as I stated. Divide that in 1/2 to get the difference (0.0205") between the hose and the fitting around the circumference. That's a difference of a little over 0.5mm ... that can EASILY be taken up with a hose clamp while using a rubber hose. As Moab stated, not sure that's significant.

Comment: After asking this question, I discovered a domestic supplier of 18 mm molded hoses for old Mercedes Benz models that I was able to cut to size.

Answer (score 0):

18 mm is closer to 3/4 inch (roughly 19mm), 5/8 of an inch is closer to 15.5 mm.
1 mm is .03937 inches you can't beat that. Go for the 3/4 inch.